# Assumptions needed by Exact Cover by 3-Sets (X3C)

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np-hard

The problem is defined as https://npcomplete.owu.edu/2014/06/10/exact-cover-by-3-sets/:

> Given a set $X$, with $|X| = 3q$ (so, the size of $X$ is a multiple of $3$), and a collection $C=\{(x_{i1},x_{i2},x_{i3})\}_{i=1}^n$ of 3-element subsets of $X$.  Can we find a subset $C’$ of $C$ where every element of $X$ occurs in exactly one member of $C’$?  (So, $C’$ is an “exact cover” of $X$).

It is known that this problem is NP-Complete. Inspired by this question about [Restriction of Exact Cover by 3-sets](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20386/restriction-of-exact-cover-by-3-sets), I was wondering if there is some underlying assumption about the relationship between $n$ and $q$ for the above NP-Completeness to hold, where $n = |C|$ is the number of 3-element subsets and $3q = |X|$ is the total number of elements?

I guess we must have $n\ge q$? Because when $n < q$, we know that all the elements in $C$ are $3n < 3q$, then the answer must be No, we can not find any subsets $C'$ where every element $X$ occurs. But is this $n\ge q$ the only assumption we need for the NP-Completeness to hold? Any thoughts or references to some proofs are appreciated.

Comment: In other words, I guess what I wanted to make sure is: is it true that X3C is NP-Complete as long as $n\ge q$? Any other assumptions about $n$ and $q$ are needed for the NP-Completeness to hold?

Comment: Take a look at an NP-hardness proof of X3C, and take it from there.